# PHP Preg_replace() pattern to replace only proper text and not image alt/src text

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to replace first occurrence of the string `"Harvey"` with the link `<a href='/harvey'>Harvey</a>`

I'm using `"/(?<!(src|alt|href)=\")".$internal_links_row['key_phrase']."/i"` as the search pattern, it only skips matching when there is exact match in the alt/src pattern.

For Eg: It matches `alt="Harvey"`. But it does not match `alt="James Stewart in Harvey",`

I need to skip every occurrence within the double quotes and I can not use `strip_tags`

Please help me guys,
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Nathan for the editing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
Harvey(?![^<>]*>)
```

Which makes sure there's no closing angled bracket ahead indicating it's inside an HTML tag.

If that doesn't work nicely, maybe a positive lookahead instead:

```
Harvey(?=[^<>]*(?:<|\Z))
```

Which makes sure there's the opening angled bracket of a tag ahead, or the end of the string.

Which translates to:

```
"/".$internal_links_row['key_phrase']."(?![^<>]*>)/i"
"/".$internal_links_row['key_phrase']."(?=[^<>]*(?:<|\Z))/i"
```

respectively

EDIT: As per comment:

```
"~".$internal_links_row['key_phrase']."(?=[^<>]*(?:<(?!/a)|\Z))~i"
 ^                                                  ^^^^^^     ^
```

I changed the delimiters and added a negative lookahead.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, I used the second method, it seems to work great, I'm checking it thoroughly..

Comment: @Mrpoppins Oops, I just noticed a typing error. The regex would be better with `(?:<|\Z)` instead of simply `<|\Z`. Apologies for that ^^;

Comment: Thanks :), and it would be even better if we can also make sure we are not replacing the text which is within the <a> tag already. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Mrpoppins Hmm, I think I might have misunderstood your question then. Could edit your question and put the input string and the desired output string?

Comment: `<p>James Stewart in Harvey</p><img src="/i/harvey.jpg" alt="poster of harvey"><a href="/harvey">Harvey</a>` . IF this is the input I only need to replace the text inside `<p> or <h1> or <div> or <span>` . Your previous code works fine, As an improvement I want it not to replace `"harvey"` within the `<a href="/harvey">Harvey</a>`, so that it does not become `<a href="/harvey"><a href="/harvey">Harvey</a></a>`

Comment: @Mrpoppins Hi, sorry for the delay, I got something urgent to do. I've updated my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

why not use `str_replace()`

```
$ans = str_replace('href="/harvey", 'href="/some_string"', $subject);
```

Comment: I want to replace the string "Harvey" that is proper text and not inside <img> or other tag. For eg: <p>Harvey is a 1950's comedy movie starring James Stewart</p><img src="harvey.jpg" alt="JS in Harvey">. I only want "Harvey" to be replaced when it is not inside <img>. But the str_replace will replace it everywhere

Comment: sorry, to distracted. i'd use domdocument, regex can be fickle when parsing html.